# $G(k)/H(k)$ as a submanifold of $G/H(k)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

Let $k$ be a local field (if necessary, assume characteristic zero).  In general, if $X$ is a smooth variety of finite type over $k$ of dimension $n$, then the set of $k$-rational points $X(k)$ is an analytic manifold over $k$ of dimension $n$.  I was thinking about the passage $X \mapsto X(k)$ from smooth varieties to manifolds in the context of coset spaces, and had a couple of questions.

Let $H$ be a closed subgroup of a linear algebraic group $G$ over $k$.  Assume $H$ is defined over $k$.  Then the coset space $G/H$ has the structure of a smooth quasi-projective variety over $k$, which tells us that $G/H(k)$ is an analytic manifold over $k$ of dimension $n = \operatorname{Dim}G - \operatorname{Dim}H$.

On the other hand, $H(k)$ is a closed subgroup of the analytic Lie group $G(k)$, and the quotient $G(k)/H(k)$ has the structure of an $n$ dimensional analytic manifold (the quotient map $G(k) \rightarrow G(k)/H(k)$ is a principal fiber bundle with $H(k)$ as a fiber).  This just follows from the general theory of Lie groups.

Of course, $G(k)/H(k)$ injects into $G/H(k)$, but they don't have to be equal.  They are the same if  $H^1(\operatorname{Gal}(k_s/k),H) $ is trivial.

What can we say about the inclusion $G(k)/H(k) \rightarrow G/H(k)$ from the perspective of manifolds?  Is the inclusion an analytic map?  Does it make $G(k)/H(k)$ into an open submanifold?  How different can these two manifolds be?

Comment: Would you specify what you call a local field? Everybody agrees that $\mathbf{Q}_p$ is a local field, but some define it as an arbitrary nondiscrete locally compact field (which is a reasonable setting for your question), while others would exclude $\mathbf{R}$ but would allow some non-locally compact fields such as Laurent Series over infinite discrete fields.

Comment: Borel-Serre (CMH 1964) obtains the finiteness of the relevant cohomology groups when one has a perfect field with finitely many extensions of each degree. This probably yields the openness result in this case. The openness result fails for the non-perfect locally compact field $K=\mathbf{F}_p((t))$ and $G\to G/H$ for $G=\mathrm{SL}_p$, $H=\mathrm{PGL}_p$.

Comment: I just mean $\mathbb R, \mathbb C$, or a finite extension of $\mathbb Q_p$ or $\mathbf F_q((t))$

Comment: OK: these are precisely the nondiscrete locally compact fields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $k$ has characteristic zero, then $H^1(k,H)$ is finite (Borel-Serre: 
https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=181643)
and the map $G(k)/H(k) \rightarrow (G/H)(k)$ has open image (can also be proved by the implicit function theorem). Moreover, a Baire category argument shows that this map is a homeomorphism onto the image. In positive characteristic, there is an old paper by Bernstein Zelevinsky (https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=425030; see the appendix) which says (I think) that the map is a homeo onto the image, and that the image is closed.

Comment: Could add references please ?

Comment: I guess the implicit function argument (and hence openness) works over arbitrary complete normed fields of characteristic zero, even without the finiteness condition.

Comment: @YCor: I think that is correct; you need not use Borel-Serre for openness.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/a/176011/23291

Comment: For more general results, over henselian valued fields, see http://content.algebraicgeometry.nl/2014-5/2014-5-025.pdf

Answer (score 5):

From the number of votes, it seems that the useful comment of Laurent Moret-Bailly has been under appreciated, so I thought it would be useful to explicitly record what the main theorem in the linked paper says (in community wiki mode, since this is really his answer).

**Theorem 1.2** of [GGMB14](http://content.algebraicgeometry.nl/2014-5/2014-5-025.pdf) (in the special case of $k$ a non-archimedean local field) The map $G(k)/H(k)\to (G/H)(k)$

$\bullet$ is always a homeomorphism onto its image,

$\bullet$ has closed image if $H$ satisfies the condition ($\ast$),

$\bullet$ has an open image if $H$ is smooth.

The condition ($\ast$) appearing in this theorem is technical (see Definition 2.4.3 of the paper), but $H$ satisfies the condition ($\ast$) if it has either one of the following properties: smooth, unipotent, commutative, or being a normal subgroup of a smooth group. Interestingly, there are examples of $H$ not satisfying $(\ast)$ for which the map $G(k)/H(k)\to (G/H)(k)$ has non-closed image (see example 7.1 of the paper, taking for example $k=\mathbf{F}_p(\!(T)\!)$).

Note that in characteristic $0$, (affine) group schemes (of finite type) are always smooth by a result of Cartier. Also, this puts in perspective the comment of YCor on the non-oppeness of $\text{SL}_p(K)\to \text{PGL}_p(K)$ for $K = \mathbf{F}_p(\!(T)\!)$. Finally, let me remark that the implicit function theorem should prove in all characteristic the openness of $G(k)/H(k)\to (G/H)(k)$ when $H$ is smooth (as suggested in Venkataramana's answer in characteristic $0$).